# Why would mutualizing debt in southern Europe help against the growing Euroscepticism in the region?

Tags: european-union

> At the same time, Euroscepticism has steadily grown in many other
> member states. And, following
> Brexit, there has been widespread fear of the EU falling apart. Berlin
> sees itself as being in a dilemma: political measures that could
> reduce scepticism of the EU in southern Europe, such as the further
> mutualisation of debt, would fuel such scepticism in the north,
> including in Germany – and vice versa. Berlin’s answer to this has
> been to prevent the EU from falling apart, but never with a clear idea
> of how to move forward. It has followed a policy of adapting to
> external conditions instead of shaping them.

https://ecfr.eu/wp-content/uploads/How-to-prevent-Germany-from-becoming-Eurosceptic.pdf

The report proposes that adopting a strategy of shared debt in Southern Europe might play a pivotal role in mitigating the growth of Eurosceptic sentiments. This leads to an intriguing exploration of the reasons behind such a suggestion, particularly when Southern European nations are already reaping substantial advantages from their association with the European Union. Is there any particular grievance that Southern Europe has that would be addressed by the mutualization of debt for example?

Comment: You need to be clearer about what the "mutualization of debt", in the EU context, consists of.  Not so much to allow people to write better answers (if you don't know what it means, you shouldn't answer in the first place).  As it is to enlighten *readers* of the question why it would matter being asked about in the first place.  I suspect a clearer definition will go a long way to explain why Southern EU states like the idea and makes them feel warm and fuzzy towards the EU.

Comment: 'when Southern European nations are already reaping substantial advantages from their association with the European Union'. Well, they think they don't. Check out some polls in Greece etc.

Comment: This is a little dated, but it should give you an idea https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-eu-referendum-36471989